# how to add google 1 button using asp MVC 4 and add in internet application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, google-plus-one

how to add google +1 button using asp MVC 4 and add in internet application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/

Adding a Google +1 button doesn't have much to do with MVC 4 per se, but a potential implementation looks something like this:

### In View/Partial View

```
<footer>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="g-plusone" data-annotation="none"></div>
        </li>

        @* other buttons/links/whatever *@

    </ul>
</footer>
```

### In _Layout.cshtml corresponding to the View

```
<script>
    (function() {
        var po = document.createElement( 'script' ); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
        po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName( 'script' )[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore( po, s );
    } )();
</script>
```

Note that you might load this script conditionally, place it within a `@section`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

For that firstly you have to create opnID auth key
for more informations you can check out this link:
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-an-asp-net-mvc4-application-with-ef-and-webapi/